# Trying to put data into a SQL Server database from textbox and some data from another table in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to enter some data into `table2` from textboxes and some data from A SQL Server database `table1`, but all logic failed. Please help.

Here is the code:

```
string qry = "insert into sale (inno,date,type,custname,item,qty,price,dis,disa,gst,gsta,total) values (" + invoice + ",'" + dt + "','" + paytype + "','" + custname + "','" + item + "'," + iqty + "," + iprice + "," + idisc + "," + idsa + "," + igst + "," + igsta + "," + itot + ") and insert into sale (hsn,sgst,cgst) select hsn,sgst,cgst from stock";

SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(qry, con);

int i = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (i >= 1)
    MessageBox.Show("Inserted successfully");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Not done");
```

Comment: Learn to use parameters!

Comment: Check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I've never seen the syntax where you use "and" between 2 insert statements before.  Is that valid?  New?... usually I'd separate with a semicolon

Comment: if i use semicolon in between then it creates too many duplicate NULL rows in table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, load your data from a table(using SQL ) and/or TextBox then store it to a local variable after that insert to your desired table using SQL.

Comment: thanks boss your method works i declare all the data into a variable and then store in another table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to see what happened here from the info you have shared, for the very least you should write what result or what exception you got and what db you are using. Despite that, I would bet that at least some of the columns you are trying to populate in the table are from the type varchar (or string or whatever), and you didn't put a value inside ' ' or didn't properly escaped your strings (if one of the variable contains the ' sign your query would fail and possibly destroy your DB with sql injection).
 I could also mention the fact that the code is unmaintainable and some other possible problems, but it's not the time or place for that.